# Antiforgery throws bad request in asp.net core web api angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to add anti-forgery to my asp.net core 3.1 web API by adding a filter in the startup file.

```
options => options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute())
```

This web API is consumed by my angular app which is hosted in a different port. I have done all the configuration which is specified in Microsoft docs as below.

```
app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
            if (path != null)
            {
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN",
                  tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions
                  {
                      HttpOnly = false,
                      Path = "/",
                  }
                );
            }
            return next(context);
        });
```

In services

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        });
```

It generates two tokens one is.Asp.NetCore.AntiForgery and XSRF-TOKEN. I am getting this token in my client app and sending it to API as request header as x-xsrf-token but it fails every time. I have set up my cors to allow any origin. I am getting token as below in my angular app.

```
let xsrfToken = this.xsrfTokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
  if(xsrfToken){
    request = request.clone({headers: request.headers.set("X-XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfToken)});
  }
```

Let me explain to you my flow. I have an identity server, web API, and angular app all of which are hosted in different ports. The angular app redirects to the identity server for authentication once it's done it will be redirected back to my client app. I have set up this csrf in web API. so basically, the authentication happens using a bearer token. I know that we don't need csrf protection because we already use a bearer token as my authentication mechanism. But I need it to work for csrf as well. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar flow and I encountered a similar problem. In my case, I did not use the Configure method but instead I created a separate Endpoint that allows me to request the cookies.

```
var aft = _antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
            Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", aft.RequestToken, new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = false,
                Secure = true,
                Domain = config.Domain
            });
```

Initially I was doing the logging in part the cookie part in the same request and that lead to every request being rejected with a 400 Bad Request token **but once I separated the login part and the cookies part in two separated endpoints and made two requests, everything worked as expected.**